# Microsoft Surface Input Simulator error (driver has timed out)

Tags: surface

When i run the SDK simulator tool, i get an error that the "Driver to the input simulator has timed out". My laptop is on Windows 10. I tried to run it from administrator, it was useless.
Any idea how to solve it?